# Define Python list based on condition

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have an API pull with a dictionary in the parameter. The value of the dictionary is a list. I need to pull entries that their dictionary attirbute contains a certain value. I thought about a few alternatives, but I think the only way is to define a "dynamic list" that contains a certain value, and define the dictionary based on that.

Example: I have the following two data points with a dictionary attribute:

data A contains `{"source":["website","newsletter"]}`, 
data B contains `{"source":["website","referral"]}`

I want to pull all the data that contains "website" as one of their sources. Source is the dictionary key which contains a list as its value.

I am trying to define a "dynamic list" so that I can define the following dictionary `{"source":[all lists that contain 'website' inside]}` and feed it into API. I am open to other ways of tackling this e.g. tweak the dictionary definition too. Thanks!

Comment: How many of these `Data A` and `Data B` dictionaries do you have? Are they all in a list or dictionary themselves, or just flying around in a bunch of variables? Is there more to these `Data A`, `Data B` dictionaries, or just a single entry with `Source` and a list as value? Is there any particular part of this that you are stuck on, it feels rather straight forward to search `dataA["source"]` to see if it contains `"website"` and then add that list to your output.

Comment: The base is this simple API query: r = requests.get(f"{ROOT_URL}/{endpoint}", auth=(API_KEY, ''), params=params)

"params" is a dictionary to specify what data I want to pull. I can specify it as params={"source":["website","newsletter"]} which would give me the exact data that its source attribute is website and newsletter. I want to specify it as {"source":[all sources that contains website]}. 

Does that better explain? So Data a and Data B are json objects, not dictionaries. They contain many dictionary attributes, but I will base my query on a single one. Thank you!